# Bean property 'sakilaDao' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing a Spring Program which is working fine with MVC Architecture. But showing the below error after basic spring implementation.

```
Error creating bean with name 'manager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'SakilaDao' of bean class [com.java.Training.managerImpl.SakilaManagerImpl]: Bean property 'SakilaDao' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dao" class="com.java.Training.DaoImpl.SakilaDaoImpl">
    </bean>


    <bean id="manager" class="com.java.Training.managerImpl.SakilaManagerImpl">
        <property name="SakilaDao" ref="dao"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**SakilaAction.java**

```
package com.java.Training.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.java.Training.manager.SakilaManager;
import com.java.Training.managerImpl.SakilaManagerImpl;
import com.java.Training.model.SakilaPojo;

public class SakilaAction {
    
    // PARAMETERS
    private String start;
    private String limit;
    private String sort;
    private String filter;
    
    // RETURN VALUE
    private String result;
    
    // SakilaManager manager= new SakilaManagerImpl();
    private HashMap <String, Object> dataMap= new HashMap <String, Object>();
    
    
    
    public String getData() {
        
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        SakilaManager manager = (SakilaManager) context.getBean("manager");
        
        try {
                
            ArrayList <SakilaPojo> jArray= (ArrayList<SakilaPojo>) manager.getData(Integer.parseInt(start), Integer.parseInt(limit), filter, sort);
            Integer count= manager.getCount(Integer.parseInt(start), Integer.parseInt(limit), filter);
            
            dataMap.put("Data", jArray);
            dataMap.put("Total", count);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        setResult(gson.toJson(dataMap));
        return "success";
    }
    
    
    
    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
    public String getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }
    public void setLimit(String limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    public String getSort() {
        return sort;
    }
    public void setSort(String sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }
    public String getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    public void setFilter(String filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    
    
}
```

**SakilaManagerImpl.java**

```
package com.java.Training.managerImpl;

import java.util.List;

import com.java.Training.Dao.SakilaDao;
import com.java.Training.DaoImpl.SakilaDaoImpl;
import com.java.Training.manager.SakilaManager;
import com.java.Training.model.SakilaPojo;

public class SakilaManagerImpl implements SakilaManager{
    
    SakilaDaoImpl dao;
    // = new SakilaDaoImpl();
    
    public List<SakilaPojo> getData(Integer start, Integer limit, String filter, String sort) {
        return dao.getData(start, limit, filter, sort);
    }
    public int getCount(Integer start, Integer limit, String filter) {
        return dao.getCount(start, limit, filter);
    }
    
    public SakilaDaoImpl getDao() {
        return dao;
    }
    public void setDao(SakilaDaoImpl dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
}
```

**SakilaManager.java**

```java
package com.java.Training.manager;

import java.util.List;

import com.java.Training.model.SakilaPojo;

public interface SakilaManager {
    
    public List<SakilaPojo> getData(Integer start, Integer limit, String filter, String sort);
    public int getCount(Integer start, Integer limit, String filter);
}
```

In *SakilaManagerImpl.java* I've tried using `SakilaDao dao;` in place of `SakilaDaoImpl dao;` which is the Interface of `SakilaDaoImpl` class. But same it's throwing the same error.

Comment: You should have an Interface, this is the basic principle of spring and by this, it will facilitate the loose coupling. Please add interface, make all required changes and edit the post.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an entirely outdated style instead of using Spring Boot? Note that if the DAO is a required dependency (and it is), you should be using constructor injection. Modern Spring (4.3+) requires no annotations at all to understand to use constructor injection if you have only a single constructor on a class.

Comment: Hi @Niraj, I've implemented all Interfaces. Just didn't include it all since the error was from `SakilaManagerImpl.java` file.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I'm new to Spring. Just learning the basic use cases and implementation. Will try to update my skills.

Comment: I am referring to SakilaManagerImpl.java where you need the dependency of dao. Declare Interface type and use the same name in XML too.

Comment: Got it now. I'll update the same. Thanks :)

Comment: I very strongly recommend you use the [Getting Started Guide with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). It's the way Spring applications have been developed for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the property name in the xml must match the field name in SakilaManagerImpl

```html
 <bean id="manager" class="com.java.Training.managerImpl.SakilaManagerImpl">
        <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: This solution worked completely. Thanks a lot.